# Does NMT include NIO direct buffer?

Tags: java, jvm

I saw before somebody said it is in the `Internal` part.(can't find now..)
But I read from [NMT Memory Categories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr022.html):

> Internal:
>   Memory that does not fit the previous categories, such as the memory used by the command line parser, JVMTI, properties and so on.

But what "so on" means....

Now I calculate memory using NMT committed + java.nio.BufferPool.But maybe duplicate some part.

So can you give me any document about this? thx :)

Comment: That’s how I would read that table. The NMT is subdivided in the listed catogaries, hence, includes them.

Comment: Yes, it does. See the linked answer.

Comment: @Holger thx~~~~

Comment: @apangin thx~~~~